# Does asp.net remove <script> tags in repeaters and inside the <% for loop %> in mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have some `<script type="javascript"/script` tags inside both a repeater and a for loop in mvc.

On page render the script is gone and is not displayed both inside the repeater and the for loop (they are separate).

Is there some option I need to set to stop this from happening? Has anyone faced this kind of issue?

Comment: Why would you have script tags where they would be repeated, anyway?  I can't think of any way this makes sense.

Comment: Also, I believe this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455912/script-script-inside-a-repeater-control-code-not-showing-up-in-the-source-code

Comment: They are repeated because I am using javascript to invoke an audio flash player. There are many "songs" on one page. Also, it is related to the other post but I found that the error is generic and occurs generally in repeaters and in for loops. The other question was specific to that repeater...

Answer (score 0):

Based on url: [<script>...</script> inside a repeater control code not showing up in the source code on page render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455912/script-script-inside-a-repeater-control-code-not-showing-up-in-the-source-code) you are injecting the javascript into the repeater using the code behind.

For testing purposes, can you try placing your script tags within the ItemTemplate?

My second suggestion would be to pass the values required to construct the javascript as part of your datasource and then output them as part of your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AudioPlayer.embed('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>', {soundFile: '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Url")%>'});
</script>
```

Regards

Gavin